# :vsp sometimes making one split bigger than other and hiding NERDTree

Tags: buffers, vim-windows, neovim, split, plugin-nerdtree

So most of the time I have my standard layout like this:

[image]

And every now and then I want to open a split in the main buffer using `:vsp` and most of the time that looks like this:

[image]

And that is what I want but sometimes (particularly if I have been in a project for a while) when I use `:vsp` in the main buffer it makes the right hand split bigger than the left and pushing NERDTree off screen like so:

[image]

Has anyone experienced this or know of what could be causing this???

UPDATE: I have figured out it is fzf.vim causing this with:

`let g:fzf_layout = { 'window': 'enew' }`

enabled, after I perform a search using FZF my splits resize incorrectly.